# I’m putting a ceiling fan in a new house that was pre wired. It’s three wired with two hot wires, black & red. the switch will not turn any power off

Tags: electrical

I’m putting a ceiling fan in a new house that was pre wired. It’s three wired with two hot wires, black & red.  the switch will not turn any power off. How does the fan turn off with switch that was pre wired

Comment: Edit pictures into your question with the fan and switch wires showing(two pictures).

Comment: As in, with the breaker off, pull the switch out of its box (remove the mounting screws) but do NOT remove any wires from their connections to the switch, and be sure the pictures *clearly show* the connections. Likewise, we need to the wires and any connections at the fan location. [Edit] those into your question.

Comment: In addition to pictures, please describe what you did to determine "the switch" will not turn any power off.  There should be two switches.  Do you measure 120V on red-white and also on black-white at the ceiling regardless of any switch positions?  If so, what did the switches do before you bought the fan?  Did the house come with nothing mounted at the ceiling box?  Usually there's a $5 contractor's light fixture or a boob light or *something*.